# iOS Add UDIDs without re-exporting app?

Tags: publishing, testflight, udid, apple-configurator

Whenever I'm sent UDIDs for a test device I add them to the devices list on our portal in `developer.apple.com` then I add the new device to the provisioning profile for the application then I re-export the compiled application with the new provisioning profile.

This is fun but when this is happening every other day it starts to become trivial. I've read about `testflight` but I want to make sure there isn't a better way that's already been established. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that **Test Flight** is used by apple you can export for the `App Store` then upload to `iTunesConnect` as a `pre-release` and users can download the `IPA` as long as it has `beta entitlements set`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there's a better solution if you have to add/manage devices frequently.

iOS requires an app to be signed before execution. You have basically 3 options:

- Development & Ad-Hock distribution profile: **you have to list every device UDID** which can run the app
- App Store: *no UDID list required*, you can upload the app to iTunes Connect and enable TestFlight beta testing for it, but as far as I know **there's no way to install an app which was built with an App Store profile on a device except through the new iTunes Connect / TestFlight beta** system and through the App Store of course.
- Enterprise: *no UDID list required*, install it on any device **but this requires a different type of Apple Developer account**, more expensive and more legal works (you have to "promise" that you won't distribute your app except for the members of your organization)

Only the last two does not require the device UDIDs to be listed.